# Enlarge div automatically , just to fit for the image background automatically

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying to place a image under certain div tag , but when there's no text , it won't show at all , so how can i force the div show the whole size of image background ?

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <title> This is an demo </title>
        <style>
            .board {
                background: url('1.jpg') no-repeat;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="board">Pic</div>
            <div class="board">Pic</div>
            <div class="board">Pic</div>
            <div class="board">Pic</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried background-size , it doesn't work at all (cover / contain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fix the dimensions of the `<div>` with respect to the size of the image. Otherwise it wont show.

Something similar to this

```
.board { 
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 400px;
    display: block;
}
```

<sub>Notes:</sub>

- <sub>if possible avoid the use of min-height or min-width. Use height & width instead</sub>

Comment: Since the image has a fixed size , min-height solved my problem , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `min-width` and `min-height`.

So you set the image's width and height to the `div`'s `min-width` and `min-height` respectively.

Setting them as `min-width` and `min-height` means that your `div` can expand more to fit the content. The downside is that the `div` can become bigger than the background image, and this will cause the background to repeat horizontally and vertically (by default, you can control it using `background-repeat`).

Otherwise if you don't care about expanding, you can set a fixed `width` and `height` to that `div`.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to do this with CSS dynamically , it is possible to measure the size of the image on the server and generate the css needed or with javascript on client side.

Any reason why it cant be an  tag inside your div?

Comment: so you man only <img> can be measured by browser , according to current standard ?

Comment: @warl0ck no but with a img tag the div wouldnt be empty if you dont put text in it.
css is not dynamic, neither is HTMl(mostly). that means that neither <img> og background can be "measured by browser", unless you use javascript to do it, and let it change the css accoridingly.

Answer (score -3):

Place `&nbsp;` in your div and it shall work

Comment: I didn't quiet get it , where should i place the `&nbsp;` then ?

Comment: it's not working , in this case , i replaced `Pic` from above , to '&nbsp' , but caused the image rather smaller ..

Comment: How are you going to calculate the accurate dimensions of the image with `&nbsp;`'s